# How to change default link dropdown toogle (use Bootstrap) in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, twitter-bootstrap

Example: My website is Wordpress, I have a navbar, default link navbar when click dropdown toogle is href="#", I want to click this, it's will come to my page... So, how to change href="#", I use WP_Bootstrap_Navwalker... Please Help Me !!
Update Example
Example : I have a navbar with parent menu Capalibities
https://i.stack.imgur.com/B2tKb.png
and when I click to display submenu, I can't go to page Capalibities, It's just display sub-menu....

Ex IMG here:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W6MMQ.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kHKfm.png)

Thank you so much !

Comment: I don't understand. What do you want? That the `href="#"` becomes in a link that redirect you to your home page?

Comment: whats a `toogle`?

Comment: It's mean is when I click to display submenu I can't go to the page with parent menu

Example : I have a navbar with parent menu Capalibities
https://imgur.com/Me2cPSo.png
and when I click to display submenu, I can't go to page Capalibities, It's just display sub-menu....